# How to use robotframework Selenium2Library in python selenium web driver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I created a framework using python selenium webdriver **webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/home/xyz/chromedriver")**. By using this framework, writing test cases in a Robot Framework.

When I use Selenium2Library keywords in my script I get an error saying Browser is not opened. But in reality the browser opened using python selenium webdriver.

Please help me how to use Selenium2Library keywords in my scripts.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your code, but I guess that your framework and Selenium2Library are two different modules. Selenium2Library expects that you have created a webdriver using its own keyword: "Create Webdriver" or "Open Browser." I don't think you can pass a different webdriver to Selenium2Library.